# VBA for copying selected data to new workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list in Excel from which I need to filter and copy selected data from a workbook to a bunch of new (not yet existing) workbooks. Here's what needs to be done:

In the main file there's a  table consisting of columns A-Z. In column A there are 250 unique different values which are used for sorting the data. The list needs to be looped through and filtered by each value in column A. With every filtering action all rows sharing the same values should be copied (along with column headers) and pasted in a new workbook. The new workbook needs to be created and named using the value in column A.

I'm a newbie when it comes to VBA and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Here's some code I found on a different forum (credit to WarPigl3t over at mrexcel.com) that I've trying to use. It seems to do all I need (and also some extra stuff with timestamp that's not really needed). However the .SaveAs part of the macro fails for some reason.

```
Sub CopySelectedData()
nameColumn = "A"
headerRow = 1
firstRow = 2

mainWB = getWorkbookName(ThisWorkbook.Name)
mainSht = ActiveSheet.Name
lastRow = Workbooks(mainWB).Sheets(mainSht).Range("A"  & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
filePath = getFilePath(ActiveWorkbook)
timeStamp = getTimeStamp()
Call createNewDirectory(filePath, timeStamp)
arrayOfNames = createArrayOfNames(mainWB, mainSht, firstRow, lastRow, nameColumn)
Call createNewWorkbook(mainWB, mainSht, nameColumn, headerRow, firstRow, lastRow, filePath, timeStamp, arrayOfNames)
End Sub

Function getWorkbookName(WB_Name)
mySplit = Split(WB_Name, ".")
getWorkbookName = mySplit(0)
End Function

Function getFilePath(WB) As String
getFilePath = WB.Path
End Function

Function getTimeStamp()
myNow = Now
myNow = Replace(myNow, "/", "-")
myNow = Replace(myNow, ":", "`")
getTimeStamp = myNow
End Function

Sub createNewDirectory(filePath, folderName)
MkDir (filePath & "/" & folderName)
End Sub

Function createArrayOfNames(mainWB, mainSht, firstRow, lastRow, nameColumn)
a = 0
Dim myArrayOfNames() As String
ReDim Preserve myArrayOfNames(a)
r = firstRow
Do Until r > lastRow
    myValue = Workbooks(mainWB).Sheets(mainSht).Range(nameColumn & r).Value
    addNewElementToArrayOfNames = True
    For Each element In myArrayOfNames()
        If element = myValue Then
            addNewElementToArrayOfNames = False
        End If
    Next element
    If addNewElementToArrayOfNames = True Then
        ReDim Preserve myArrayOfNames(a)
        myArrayOfNames(a) = myValue
        a = a + 1
    End If
    r = r + 1
Loop
createArrayOfNames = myArrayOfNames()
End Function

Sub createNewWorkbook(mainWB, mainSht, nameColumn, headerRow, firstRow, lastRow, filePath, timeStamp, arrayOfNames)
For Each element In arrayOfNames
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    With newWB
        .SaveAs Filename:=filePath & "\" & timeStamp & "\" & element & ".xls"
        newWB_Name = getWorkbookName(newWB.Name)
        Call createMonthlyData(newWB_Name, mainWB, mainSht, nameColumn, headerRow, firstRow, lastRow, element)
        newWB.Save
        newWB.Close
    End With
Next element
End Sub

Sub createMonthlyData(newWB_Name, mainWB, mainSht, nameColumn, headerRow, firstRow, lastRow, arrayName)
Workbooks(mainWB).Sheets(mainSht).Rows(headerRow).Copy
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Workbooks(newWB_Name).Sheets("Blad1").Rows(headerRow)
nextRow = firstRow
r = firstRow
Do Until r > lastRow
    nameValue = Workbooks(mainWB).Sheets(mainSht).Range(nameColumn & r).Value
    If nameValue = arrayName Then
        Workbooks(mainWB).Sheets(mainSht).Rows(r).Copy
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Workbooks(newWB_Name).Sheets("Blad1").Rows(nextRow)
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
    End If
    r = r + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: So... what have you tried and doesn't work?

Comment: Can you share the code that you have written and didn't work ?

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix it myself based on the code above. The reason the saveas.-part didn't work was simply because some of the values used for the naming procedure contained illegal characters. 
One question though. How do I change this part to also copy and paste the format: Workbooks(mainWB).Sheets(mainSht).Rows(r).Copy and         ActiveSheet.Paste